# Horizontal progress HUD indicator à la Instagram

Tags: ios, user-interface

Is there an open source library available out there that does a horizontal progress bar for iOS? I know `MBProgressHUD` does a circular one.

Comment: Um, [`UIProgressView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm I don't know how Instagram HUD looks, but I can figure out that you are looking for something like this:

[image: atomHUD]

Check the source code page [here](https://github.com/atomton/ATMHud) and its demo.